# Copy Pasting Syntax Problems in VBA [Edited]

Tags: excel, vba7

**Edit: I am running on Excel 2016 (if that information help)**

**Purpose:**

**I wanted to copy paste entire row for each participant `A: ___` from one worksheet `Worksheets("Sheet3")`to another worksheet `Worksheets("Sheet4")`.** based on condition `"Selected"` **(Column I)**

**Edit:
I have fixed this part below**

I have one error where variable not defined for `ParticipantCol`. And I am not sure what other particular coding has issues.

**Current Problem**

***Run-time error "9".
Subscript out of range***. Please also check if my variables are correctly defined.

I relied on these two links for reference to build the syntax below:

1. **https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/** [from 2016]
2. **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4swMZe0TEE** [from 2021]

   ```
    Sub CopyPasteIfSelectedThen2021()

    Dim SelectionStatusCol As Range
    Dim SelectionStatus As Range
    Dim PasteCell As Range

    Set SelectionStatusCol = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I2:I23")

    For Each SelectionStatus In SelectionStatusCol

        If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I2") = "Selected" Then

            Set PasteCell = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")
        Else
            Set PasteCell = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        End If

        If SelectionStatus = "Selected" Then SelectionStatus.EntireRow.Copy PasteCell


   Next SelectionStatus

   End Sub
   ```

I tried 2021 coding concept and it shown error. After adjusted towards 2016 coding method, I still experienced issues. And I am not sure where I could find specific references to specific coding for 2016 Excel version and it has taken me day 2 trying me to resolve it.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You can not use space in variable name. So, change `Selection Status Col` to `SelectionStatusCol`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. @Harun24HR. I have just adjusted this. I have new problem and have updated my current problem: **Run-time error "9". Subscript out of range**. What do I do now?

Comment: Why not just use autoFilter and paste all the visible cells in one step; or use the Advanced Filter which has a paste option included.

Comment: Great idea. I feel dumbfounded that it's such an easy step although I would need to still but not effortfully copy & paste the resulting filters into another sheet. Many thanks! However I would still let someone to answer the question for knowledge's sake and other future use :)